# Error Building Qt from Source on Windows

Tags: c++, qt, compilation

I am trying to build Qt 5.10 from source on Windows. I think I have all the dependencies installed following : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-building.html

However, I am facing a really weird issue.

The configuration I use is : `configure -skip webengine -nomake examples -nomake tests`
however "jom" seems to keep trying to compile tests and throwing the following errors:

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.10>..\jom\jom.exe > output

jom 1.1.2 - empower your cores

jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.10\qtbase\tests\auto\corelib\kernel\qcoreapplication\Makefile.Debug [debug\tst_qcoreapplication.exe] Error 1120
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.10\qtbase\tests\auto\corelib\kernel\qcoreapplication\Makefile [debug] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.10\qtbase\tests\auto\corelib\kernel\Makefile [sub-qcoreapplication-make_first] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.10\qtbase\tests\auto\corelib\Makefile [sub-kernel-make_first] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.10\qtbase\tests\auto\Makefile [sub-corelib-make_first] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.10\qtbase\tests\auto\gui\image\qpixmapcache\Makefile.Debug [debug\tst_qpixmapcache.exe] Error 1120
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.10\qtbase\tests\auto\gui\image\qpixmapcache\Makefile [debug] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.10\qtbase\tests\auto\gui\image\Makefile [sub-qpixmapcache-make_first] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.10\qtbase\tests\auto\network\kernel\qhostinfo\Makefile.Debug [debug\tst_qhostinfo.exe] Error 1120
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.10\qtbase\tests\auto\network\kernel\qhostinfo\Makefile [debug] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.10\qtbase\tests\auto\network\kernel\Makefile [sub-qhostinfo-make_first] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.10\qtbase\tests\auto\network\access\qhttpnetworkconnection\Makefile.Debug [debug\tst_qhttpnetworkconnection.exe] Error 1120
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.10\qtbase\tests\auto\network\access\qhttpnetworkconnection\Makefile [debug] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.10\qtbase\tests\auto\network\access\Makefile [sub-qhttpnetworkconnection-make_first] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.10\qtbase\tests\auto\network\Makefile [sub-access-make_first] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.10\qtbase\tests\auto\network\Makefile [sub-kernel-make_first] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.10\qtbase\tests\auto\Makefile [sub-network-make_first] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.10\qtbase\tests\auto\gui\painting\qpathclipper\Makefile.Debug [debug\tst_qpathclipper.exe] Error 1120
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.10\qtbase\tests\auto\gui\painting\qpathclipper\Makefile [debug] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.10\qtbase\tests\auto\gui\painting\Makefile [sub-qpathclipper-make_first] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.10\qtbase\tests\benchmarks\network\kernel\qhostinfo\Makefile.Release [release\tst_bench_qhostinfo.exe] Error 1120
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.10\qtbase\tests\benchmarks\network\kernel\qhostinfo\Makefile [release] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.10\qtbase\tests\benchmarks\network\kernel\Makefile [sub-qhostinfo-make_first] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.10\qtbase\tests\benchmarks\network\Makefile [sub-kernel-make_first] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.10\qtbase\tests\benchmarks\Makefile [sub-network-make_first] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.10\qtbase\tests\auto\gui\kernel\qguiapplication\Makefile.Debug [debug\tst_qguiapplication.exe] Error 1120
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.10\qtbase\tests\auto\gui\kernel\qguiapplication\Makefile [debug] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.10\qtbase\tests\auto\gui\kernel\Makefile [sub-qguiapplication-make_first] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.10\qtbase\tests\auto\gui\Makefile [sub-kernel-make_first] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.10\qtbase\tests\auto\gui\Makefile [sub-image-make_first] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.10\qtbase\tests\auto\gui\Makefile [sub-painting-make_first] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.10\qtbase\tests\auto\Makefile [sub-gui-make_first] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.10\qtbase\tests\Makefile [sub-auto-make_first] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.10\qtbase\tests\Makefile [sub-benchmarks-make_first] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.10\qtbase\Makefile [sub-tests-make_first] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.10\Makefile [module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2
```

And following are the errors faced during the build:

```
tst_qcoreapplication.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class QThreadData * __cdecl QThreadData::current(bool)" (?current@QThreadData@@SAPAV1@_N@Z) referenced in function "private: virtual void __thiscall Thread::run(void)" (?run@Thread@@EAEXXZ)
debug\tst_qcoreapplication.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
tst_qpixmapcache.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl q_QPixmapCache_keyHashSize(void)" (?q_QPixmapCache_keyHashSize@@YAHXZ) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall tst_QPixmapCache::noLeak(void)" (?noLeak@tst_QPixmapCache@@AAEXXZ)
debug\tst_qpixmapcache.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
tst_qhostinfo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl qt_qhostinfo_clear_cache(void)" (?qt_qhostinfo_clear_cache@@YAXXZ) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall tst_QHostInfo::init(void)" (?init@tst_QHostInfo@@AAEXXZ)
tst_qhostinfo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl qt_qhostinfo_enable_cache(bool)" (?qt_qhostinfo_enable_cache@@YAX_N@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall tst_QHostInfo::init(void)" (?init@tst_QHostInfo@@AAEXXZ)
debug\tst_qhostinfo.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
tst_qhttpnetworkconnection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall QHttpNetworkRequest::QHttpNetworkRequest(class QUrl const &,enum QHttpNetworkRequest::Operation,enum QHttpNetworkRequest::Priority)" (??0QHttpNetworkRequest@@QAE@ABVQUrl@@W4Operation@0@W4Priority@0@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall tst_QHttpNetworkConnection::get(void)" (?get@tst_QHttpNetworkConnection@@AAEXXZ)
tst_qhttpnetworkconnection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall QHttpNetworkRequest::QHttpNetworkRequest(class QHttpNetworkRequest const &)" (??0QHttpNetworkRequest@@QAE@ABV0@@Z) referenced in function "public: static void * __cdecl QtMetaTypePrivate::QMetaTypeFunctionHelper<class QHttpNetworkRequest,1>::Construct(void *,void const *)" (?Construct@?$QMetaTypeFunctionHelper@VQHttpNetworkRequest@@$00@QtMetaTypePrivate@@SAPAXPAXPBX@Z)
tst_qhttpnetworkconnection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall QHttpNetworkRequest::~QHttpNetworkRequest(void)" (??1QHttpNetworkRequest@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall tst_QHttpNetworkConnection::get(void)" (?get@tst_QHttpNetworkConnection@@AAEXXZ)
tst_qhttpnetworkconnection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall QHttpNetworkRequest::setHeaderField(class QByteArray const &,class QByteArray const &)" (?setHeaderField@QHttpNetworkRequest@@UAEXABVQByteArray@@0@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall tst_QHttpNetworkConnection::compression(void)" (?compression@tst_QHttpNetworkConnection@@AAEXXZ)
tst_qhttpnetworkconnection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: enum QHttpNetworkRequest::Priority __thiscall QHttpNetworkRequest::priority(void)const " (?priority@QHttpNetworkRequest@@QBE?AW4Priority@1@XZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall GetMultipleWithPrioritiesReceiver::finishedSlot(void)" (?finishedSlot@GetMultipleWithPrioritiesReceiver@@QAEXXZ)
tst_qhttpnetworkconnection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall QHttpNetworkRequest::setPriority(enum QHttpNetworkRequest::Priority)" (?setPriority@QHttpNetworkRequest@@QAEXW4Priority@1@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall tst_QHttpNetworkConnection::getMultipleWithPipeliningAndMultiplePriorities(void)" (?getMultipleWithPipeliningAndMultiplePriorities@tst_QHttpNetworkConnection@@AAEXXZ)
tst_qhttpnetworkconnection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall QHttpNetworkRequest::isPipeliningAllowed(void)const " (?isPipeliningAllowed@QHttpNetworkRequest@@QBE_NXZ) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall tst_QHttpNetworkConnection::getMultipleWithPipeliningAndMultiplePriorities(void)" (?getMultipleWithPipeliningAndMultiplePriorities@tst_QHttpNetworkConnection@@AAEXXZ)
tst_qhttpnetworkconnection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall QHttpNetworkRequest::setPipeliningAllowed(bool)" (?setPipeliningAllowed@QHttpNetworkRequest@@QAEX_N@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall tst_QHttpNetworkConnection::getMultiple(void)" (?getMultiple@tst_QHttpNetworkConnection@@AAEXXZ)
tst_qhttpnetworkconnection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall QHttpNetworkRequest::setUploadByteDevice(class QNonContiguousByteDevice *)" (?setUploadByteDevice@QHttpNetworkRequest@@QAEXPAVQNonContiguousByteDevice@@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall tst_QHttpNetworkConnection::post(void)" (?post@tst_QHttpNetworkConnection@@AAEXXZ)
tst_qhttpnetworkconnection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class QHttpNetworkRequest __thiscall QHttpNetworkReply::request(void)const " (?request@QHttpNetworkReply@@QBE?AVQHttpNetworkRequest@@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall tst_QHttpNetworkConnection::getMultipleWithPipeliningAndMultiplePriorities(void)" (?getMultipleWithPipeliningAndMultiplePriorities@tst_QHttpNetworkConnection@@AAEXXZ)
tst_qhttpnetworkconnection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall QHttpNetworkReply::statusCode(void)const " (?statusCode@QHttpNetworkReply@@QBEHXZ) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall tst_QHttpNetworkConnection::get(void)" (?get@tst_QHttpNetworkConnection@@AAEXXZ)
tst_qhttpnetworkconnection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class QString __thiscall QHttpNetworkReply::reasonPhrase(void)const " (?reasonPhrase@QHttpNetworkReply@@QBE?AVQString@@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall tst_QHttpNetworkConnection::get(void)" (?get@tst_QHttpNetworkConnection@@AAEXXZ)
tst_qhttpnetworkconnection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __int64 __thiscall QHttpNetworkReply::bytesAvailable(void)const " (?bytesAvailable@QHttpNetworkReply@@QBE_JXZ) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall tst_QHttpNetworkConnection::get(void)" (?get@tst_QHttpNetworkConnection@@AAEXXZ)
tst_qhttpnetworkconnection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class QByteArray __thiscall QHttpNetworkReply::readAny(void)" (?readAny@QHttpNetworkReply@@QAE?AVQByteArray@@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall tst_QHttpNetworkConnection::put(void)" (?put@tst_QHttpNetworkConnection@@AAEXXZ)
tst_qhttpnetworkconnection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class QByteArray __thiscall QHttpNetworkReply::readAll(void)" (?readAll@QHttpNetworkReply@@QAE?AVQByteArray@@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall tst_QHttpNetworkConnection::get(void)" (?get@tst_QHttpNetworkConnection@@AAEXXZ)
tst_qhttpnetworkconnection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall QHttpNetworkReply::setDownstreamLimited(bool)" (?setDownstreamLimited@QHttpNetworkReply@@QAEX_N@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall tst_QHttpNetworkConnection::getAndThenDeleteObject(void)" (?getAndThenDeleteObject@tst_QHttpNetworkConnection@@AAEXXZ)
tst_qhttpnetworkconnection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall QHttpNetworkReply::isFinished(void)const " (?isFinished@QHttpNetworkReply@@QBE_NXZ) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall tst_QHttpNetworkConnection::get(void)" (?get@tst_QHttpNetworkConnection@@AAEXXZ)
tst_qhttpnetworkconnection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall QHttpNetworkReply::isPipeliningUsed(void)const " (?isPipeliningUsed@QHttpNetworkReply@@QBE_NXZ) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall tst_QHttpNetworkConnection::getMultipleWithPipeliningAndMultiplePriorities(void)" (?getMultipleWithPipeliningAndMultiplePriorities@tst_QHttpNetworkConnection@@AAEXXZ)
tst_qhttpnetworkconnection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class QHttpNetworkConnection * __thiscall QHttpNetworkReply::connection(void)" (?connection@QHttpNetworkReply@@QAEPAVQHttpNetworkConnection@@XZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall tst_QHttpNetworkConnection::challenge401(class QHttpNetworkRequest const &,class QAuthenticator *)" (?challenge401@tst_QHttpNetworkConnection@@QAEXABVQHttpNetworkRequest@@PAVQAuthenticator@@@Z)
tst_qhttpnetworkconnection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall QHttpNetworkConnection::QHttpNetworkConnection(class QString const &,unsigned short,bool,enum QHttpNetworkConnection::ConnectionType,class QObject *,class QSharedPointer<class QNetworkSession>)" (??0QHttpNetworkConnection@@QAE@ABVQString@@G_NW4ConnectionType@0@PAVQObject@@V?$QSharedPointer@VQNetworkSession@@@@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall tst_QHttpNetworkConnection::get(void)" (?get@tst_QHttpNetworkConnection@@AAEXXZ)
tst_qhttpnetworkconnection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall QHttpNetworkConnection::QHttpNetworkConnection(unsigned short,class QString const &,unsigned short,bool,class QObject *,class QSharedPointer<class QNetworkSession>,enum QHttpNetworkConnection::ConnectionType)" (??0QHttpNetworkConnection@@QAE@GABVQString@@G_NPAVQObject@@V?$QSharedPointer@VQNetworkSession@@@@W4ConnectionType@0@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall tst_QHttpNetworkConnection::getMultiple(void)" (?getMultiple@tst_QHttpNetworkConnection@@AAEXXZ)
tst_qhttpnetworkconnection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall QHttpNetworkConnection::~QHttpNetworkConnection(void)" (??1QHttpNetworkConnection@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall tst_QHttpNetworkConnection::get(void)" (?get@tst_QHttpNetworkConnection@@AAEXXZ)
tst_qhttpnetworkconnection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class QString __thiscall QHttpNetworkConnection::hostName(void)const " (?hostName@QHttpNetworkConnection@@QBE?AVQString@@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall tst_QHttpNetworkConnection::get(void)" (?get@tst_QHttpNetworkConnection@@AAEXXZ)
tst_qhttpnetworkconnection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: unsigned short __thiscall QHttpNetworkConnection::port(void)const " (?port@QHttpNetworkConnection@@QBEGXZ) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall tst_QHttpNetworkConnection::get(void)" (?get@tst_QHttpNetworkConnection@@AAEXXZ)
tst_qhttpnetworkconnection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class QHttpNetworkReply * __thiscall QHttpNetworkConnection::sendRequest(class QHttpNetworkRequest const &)" (?sendRequest@QHttpNetworkConnection@@QAEPAVQHttpNetworkReply@@ABVQHttpNetworkRequest@@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall tst_QHttpNetworkConnection::get(void)" (?get@tst_QHttpNetworkConnection@@AAEXXZ)
tst_qhttpnetworkconnection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall QHttpNetworkConnection::isSsl(void)const " (?isSsl@QHttpNetworkConnection@@QBE_NXZ) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall tst_QHttpNetworkConnection::get(void)" (?get@tst_QHttpNetworkConnection@@AAEXXZ)
tst_qhttpnetworkconnection.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const QHttpNetworkReply::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@QHttpNetworkReply@@2UQMetaObject@@B)
debug\tst_qhttpnetworkconnection.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 27 unresolved externals
    cd qsslerror\ && ( if not exist Makefile C:\Qt\Qt5.10\qtbase\bin\qmake.exe -o Makefile C:\Qt\Qt5.10\qtbase\tests\auto\network\ssl\qsslerror\qsslerror.pro ) && C:\Qt\jom\jom.exe -f Makefile
    cd qsqlerror\ && ( if not exist Makefile C:\Qt\Qt5.10\qtbase\bin\qmake.exe -o Makefile C:\Qt\Qt5.10\qtbase\tests\auto\sql\kernel\qsqlerror\qsqlerror.pro ) && C:\Qt\jom\jom.exe -f Makefile
tst_qpathclipper.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall QWingedEdge::QWingedEdge(void)" (??0QWingedEdge@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall tst_QPathClipper::testWingedEdge(void)" (?testWingedEdge@tst_QPathClipper@@AAEXXZ)
tst_qpathclipper.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall QWingedEdge::QWingedEdge(class QPainterPath const &,class QPainterPath const &)" (??0QWingedEdge@@QAE@ABVQPainterPath@@0@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall tst_QPathClipper::testWingedEdge(void)" (?testWingedEdge@tst_QPathClipper@@AAEXXZ)
tst_qpathclipper.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: struct QWingedEdge::TraversalStatus __thiscall QWingedEdge::next(struct QWingedEdge::TraversalStatus const &)const " (?next@QWingedEdge@@QBE?AUTraversalStatus@1@ABU21@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall tst_QPathClipper::testWingedEdge(void)" (?testWingedEdge@tst_QPathClipper@@AAEXXZ)
tst_qpathclipper.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall QWingedEdge::addEdge(class QPointF const &,class QPointF const &)" (?addEdge@QWingedEdge@@QAEHABVQPointF@@0@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall tst_QPathClipper::testWingedEdge(void)" (?testWingedEdge@tst_QPathClipper@@AAEXXZ)
debug\tst_qpathclipper.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl qt_qhostinfo_clear_cache(void)" (?qt_qhostinfo_clear_cache@@YAXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall tst_qhostinfo::init(void)" (?init@tst_qhostinfo@@QAEXXZ)
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl qt_qhostinfo_enable_cache(bool)" (?qt_qhostinfo_enable_cache@@YAX_N@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall tst_qhostinfo::lookupSpeed(void)" (?lookupSpeed@tst_qhostinfo@@AAEXXZ)
release\tst_bench_qhostinfo.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
tst_qcoreapplication.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class QThreadData * __cdecl QThreadData::current(bool)" (?current@QThreadData@@SAPAV1@_N@Z) referenced in function "private: virtual void __thiscall Thread::run(void)" (?run@Thread@@EAEXXZ)
debug\tst_qguiapplication.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Please provide any insight into this and how could I potentially fix this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!!

Comment: I think there is an earlier error in the output your image is missing, check and insert it into your question. Also always copy paste text as text not as an image.

Comment: Updated! I extracted every line containing error form the output.